# alfresco ---- how to add event handler into surf template?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, alfresco, surf

```
        <div class="yui-gd">
            <div class="yui-u first"><label for="${args.htmlid}-addContent">${msg("label.HowToAddContent")}:</label></div>
            <div class="yui-u"> 
              <select id="addContent" name="addContent" onchange="dropdown(this)">
                  <option value="1" selected="selected">${msg("label.generateFromDescription")}</option>
                  <option value="2">${msg("label.uploadFile")}</option>
               </select>   
              </div>   

         </div>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
       function dropdown(sel){
              //if(document.getElementById("addContent").value == "1")
            if(sel.value == "0"){
               document.getElementById('desc').style.display = 'block'
         }
            else {
            document.getElementById('desc').style.display = 'none'
         }
      }       
//]]></script>
```

I write it because i want to add event handler into select box, it works well in firefox, but in IE it always throw null exception.
Even through i used attachEvent , it still can not work in IE.
If i use document.getElementById("addContent") in  above, it will always throw null exception!
But all these things work well in Firefox!

Can someone tell me why ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which IE version are you using?
If it's an old version, try to get the selected value through the options:

```
var selectedValue = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
```